# How do I find the intersection of a set of tuples while ignoring the last element of the tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Edit: Solved

I've solved this by creating dictionaries `a` and `b` where the keys are the tuples `(x,y)` and my values are the integers `t`. I then return my keys as sets, take the built-in `intersection`, then `get` the values for all intersecting `(x,y)` points.

```
a{(x,y): t, ...}
b{(x,y): t, ...}
c = set([*a]).intersection(set([*b]))
for each in c:
    val_a = a.get(each)
    val_b = b.get(each)
```

### Original Question

I have two sets of tuples, each of the form

```
a = {(x,y,t), (x,y,t), ...}
b = {(x,y,t), (x,y,t), ...}
```

I'd like to find the "intersection" of `a` and `b` while ignoring the `t` element of the tuples.

For example:

```
a = {(1,2,5), (4,6,7)}
b = {(1,2,7), (5,5,3)}
c = a.magicintersection(b,'ignore-last-element-of-tuple-magic-keyword')
```

where `c`, the desired output, would yield `{(1,2,5), (1,2,7)}`.

I'd like to leverage the built-in `intersection` function rather than writing my own (horribly inefficient) function but I can't see a way around this.

Comment: What's the expected output. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: You could derive a new class from tuple (or create a completely new class) which returns a hash based on the first two elements only and tests equality only on them. You would then have to store instances of this class in the sets.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the built in intersection methods for that. You also can't attach function to built ins:

```
def magic_intersect(x):
    pass

set.mi = magic_intersect
```

results in

```
    set.mi = magic_intersect
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'set'
```

---

You could prop them all into a dictionary with keys of the 1st two elements of each tuple and values of set/list all tuples that match this to get the result:

```
a = {(1,2,5), (4,6,7)}
b = {(1,2,7), (5,5,3)}

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)

for x in (a,b):
    for s in x: 
        d[(s[0],s[1])].add(s)

print(d)
print(d.get( (1,2) )) # get all tuples that start with (1,2,_)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {
    (4, 6): {(4, 6, 7)}, 
    (1, 2): {(1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 7)}, 
    (5, 5): {(5, 5, 3)}})

{(1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 7)}
```

but thats only going to be worth it if you need to query for those multiple times and do not need to put millions of sets in them.

The actual "lookup" of what 2-tuple has which 3-tuples is O(1) fast - but you need space/time to build the dictionary.

This approch looses the information from wich set of tuples the items came - if you need to preserve that as well, you would have to store that as well - somehow.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling I'd likely have to use a dictionary which I'm not familiar with. I will look into something of this form.

Answer (score 0):

What would your "intersection" have as a result, if the third component varies?

Anyway, the way to do this is to have a dictionary where the key is a tuple with the components of interest. The dictionary values can be lists with all matching 3-tuples, and then you can select just those which have more than one element.

This is not inefficient, you will only have to walk each set once - so it is O(M + N)  - and you have a lot of lists and thousands of tuples with the the same x, y  - then building the dictionary will append the matching tuples to a list, which is O(1).

```
matches = {}
for series_of_tuples in (a, b):
    for tuple in series_of_tuples:
       matches.setdefault(tuple[:2], []).append(tuple)

intersection = [values for values in matches.values() if len(values) > 1]
```

Comment: Thanks -- I took your suggestion and created a dictionary where each key was the tuple (x,y) of interest and set the values to the integers t.